# Development Workflow - Bootstrap (Less), Bower and Grunt

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs, less, workflow, bower

I am trying to step up my game as far as my folder structure and workflow is considered. I have recently discovered that front end package management and automation of tasks are key to improve speed, decreasing dev time, decrease file size and increase profit.

My issue is I am not too sure what the best method of using these tools are. I have a builds folder, which includes a dev and prod folder. My components are outside this folder in the bower_components folder.

I usually customise bootstrap and take advantage of it's variables file and mixins. I have copied the bootstrap.less file, and the variables.less file, and placed them in builds->dev->less. I then have grunt compiling the less using the bootstrap.less file from this new directory.

Is this the best way to go about using bootstrap and it's less files in this setup? I want to use bower due to it's power, but I also want to keep the power of customising bootstrap and it's less files.

What do you guys think?

NB: I usually code themes for brochure websites and very small applications.

Comment: you don't have to copy bootstrap.less and variables.less. Less uses lazy loading and last declaration wins for variables, so to can put their definition afterwards to (re)assign them. Create a project.less file which `@import`s bootstrap.less from your bower folder and put your custom variables assignments, mixins, and code after the `@import`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I think that you misunderstood me or I misunderstood your response. The bootstrap.less file and the variables.less are bootstrap's. I edit bootstrap's variables.less file to make things much easier when developing. So are you saying I should copy bootstrap's variables.less file to my LESS folder. Create a project.less file next to it. Then in this project.less file, import bootstrap.less from the bower folder and import the vairables.less file from my LESS folder? That does not seem to make that much sense? Could you please clarify? Thanks.

Comment: Nope. Your less folder should only contain the (new) project file. Which looks like: `@import "../bower_components/bootstrap.less"; @brand-primary: yellow;`. So you don't have to change any of Bootstrap's files. Your project file only (re)declare the variable you have to change.

Comment: wow thanks. interesting. so that makes a lot of sense. I will give it a go and let you know. I am finding it very difficult to work with bower and grunt. having a production or dist folder is tricky. My next issue is finding out how  to call the paths in web pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As posted above by Bass Jobsen:

you don't have to copy bootstrap.less and variables.less. Less uses lazy loading and last declaration wins for variables, so to can put their definition afterwards to (re)assign them. Create a project.less file which @imports bootstrap.less from your bower folder and put your custom variables assignments, mixins, and code after the @import