# What is the easiest way to compile LESS files to a CSS folder?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

What is the easiest way to do this?

I have a simple one page Boostrap website with a `less` folder and a `css` folder.

I have no way of making changes to the .less files and having them compile as a .css file in the `css` folder.

I have tried instructions on [Grunt.js via Boostrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/), which compiles everything to a `dist` folder inside `node_modules` but I don't want to include the entire build system when I publish my website. And I don't want to have to manually copy and paste the `css` folder from the build system.

I tried the instructions on [Less](http://lesscss.org/) and had no idea which files were where. In the past I used Compass but it only works with Sass.

I feel like this should be really easy, anything that I'm overlooking?

Comment: 1) install node, which includes npm already (see: https://nodejs.org/download/) 2) run `npm install less` 3) now you can do: lessc less/bootstap.less css/website.less. Pretty easy isn't it? Finally notice two things. a) compiling bootstrap requires the autoprefix postprocessor; you can install it by running `npm install less-plugin-autoprefix`, see also: http://bassjobsen.weblogs.fm/compile-bootstrap-less-v2-autoprefix-plugin/ and b) you should not directly edit Bootstrap source files: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30071940/development-workflow-bootstrap-less-bower-and-grunt

Comment: You can also use a tool like [koala](http://koala-app.com/) to auto compile your less sources every time you save. Just add your project and set an output path to your CSS. Koala does the rest.

Comment: @Demnogonis to compile Bootstrap (with the same browser support) Kaola should run the require autoprefixer too. The good news Kaola seems to support the autoprefixer already and support for configuration will come soon too: https://github.com/oklai/koala/pull/401